# Simple integer field saves as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null

I recently added a new mapicon_id field to my venue records which displays all availiable icons in a dropdown on new and edit. Each record also has top and left integer fields which allow me to give coords for absolute positioning of the icons using javascript.

Before I added the new mapicon_id field the top and left fields worked fine but now the left field wont save. You can edit the field or create a new record with a left value and click save, it will then give the successfull flash message and redirect correctly but the field will be blank.

venue partial:

```
<%= link_to venue do %>
  <div class="venue_partial">

    <div class="venue_icon">
      <%= image_tag venue.venuetype.photo.url(:thumb), :class => 'image' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to venue do %>
  <div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;"><%= image_tag venue.mapicon.photo.url(:thumb), :class => 'venue_map_icon' %></div>
<% end %>

<script>
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.left %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.top %>px";
</script>
```

edit and new:

```
<%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
  <p>name: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p>mapicon: <br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:mapicon_id, Mapicon.all, :id, :name) %>

  <p>top: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :top %></p>

  <p>left: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :left %></p>

  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

development log on editing a record with top and left values of 100:

```
Started GET "/venues/45-test-place/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-26 11:07:10 +0000
  Processing by VenuesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"45-test-place"}
  [1m[35mVenue Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `venues`.* FROM `venues` WHERE `venues`.`id` = 45 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mArea Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `areas`.* FROM `areas`[0m
  [1m[35mVenuetype Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `venuetypes`.* FROM `venuetypes`
  [1m[36mMapicon Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `mapicons`.* FROM `mapicons`[0m
Rendered venues/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (108.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 127.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started POST "/venues/45-test-place" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-26 11:07:16 +0000
  Processing by VenuesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"By8blc3esfE6A8tnfOmRPn9f4KZb/ctwpjg86La4d1Y=", "venue"=>{"name"=>"test place", "addressline1"=>"", "addressline2"=>"", "addressline3"=>"", "phonenumber"=>"", "area_id"=>"8", "venuetype_id"=>"15", "mapicon_id"=>"1", "top"=>"100", "left"=>"100"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"45-test-place"}
  [1m[35mVenue Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `venues`.* FROM `venues` WHERE `venues`.`id` = 45 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  UPDATE `venues` SET `top` = 100, `left` = 100, `updated_at` = '2011-02-26 11:07:16' WHERE `venues`.`id` = 45
  [1m[36mSQL (30.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/venues.45-test-place
Completed 302 Found in 65ms
```

After editing this record the top field shows 100 but the left field is blank.

venue model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :area
  belongs_to :venuetype
  belongs_to :mapicon

  scope :with_type, lambda { |types|
    types.present? ? where(:venuetype_id => types) : scoped }

  scope :with_area, lambda { |areas|
    areas.present? ? where(:area_id => areas) : scoped }

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
  end

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

mapicon model:

```
class Mapicon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100>",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :large =>   "400x400>" },
    :default_url => '/images/noimage.png'
end
```

**UPDATE**

I dropped the top and left fields and added toppx and leftpx so the field names aren't so generic, however the problem still exists only now its the toppx field that wont save. Also, If I change the javascript to take the value of the venuetype_id instead of the toppx value it displays correctly. the venuetype_id is 15 and the icon is displayed 15px from the top of the page.

new migration:

```
class AddToppxAndLeftpxToVenues < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_column :venues, :toppx, :integer
    add_column :venues, :leftpx, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :venues, :toppx
    remove_column :venues, :leftpx
  end
end
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

```
irb(main):002:0> v=Venue.new
=> #<Venue id: nil, name: nil, addressline1: nil, addressline2: nil, addressline
3: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, area_id: nil, user_id: nil, venuetype_
id: nil, phonenumber: nil, toppx: nil, leftpx: nil>
irb(main):003:0> v.name='test23'
=> "test23"
irb(main):004:0> v.leftpx='24'
=> "24"
irb(main):005:0> v.toppx='42'
=> "42"
irb(main):006:0> v.venuetype_id='13'
=> "13"
irb(main):007:0> v.area_id='2'
=> "2"
irb(main):008:0> v.user_id='6'
=> "6"
irb(main):009:0> v.save
=> true
irb(main):010:0> Venue.find(:last)
=> #<Venue id: 55, name: "test23", addressline1: nil, addressline2: nil, address
line3: nil, created_at: "2011-02-28 18:07:42", updated_at: "2011-02-28 18:07:42"
, area_id: 2, user_id: 946706424, venuetype_id: 13, phonenumber: nil, toppx: nil
, leftpx: 24>
irb(main):011:0>
```

On a side note I dont know whats happening with the change of user_id there but it works correctly and associates to the correct user.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The left field is being passed as `100` in the `POST` request log, so the view code is probably fine. How about the model code? Post that too?

Comment: @sarnold thanks for having a look, added the venue and mapicon model code

Comment: I'm stumped, it all looks too simple to fail. How about controller code too? If nothing else, adding controller code ought to bring the question to the top of the activity list for those who prefer to view questions that way...

Comment: you can load whole project to github to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by sticking a new copy of libmySQL.dll into the ruby bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query that Rails did (UPDATE ...) looks fine, so must either not be saved correctly by your database, or Rails doesn't get it back from the DB correctly.

Have a look at the database. Do a SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = 45, and look at that result to see if it's correctly saved there. Also, post your schema (DESCRIBE venues).

Comment: I've added to the end of my question what happens when I add a record from the console, Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use `toppx` and `leftpx` istead just `top` and `left`:

```
<%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
  <p>name: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <p>mapicon: <br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:mapicon_id, Mapicon.all, :id, :name) %>

  <p>top: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :toppx %></p>

  <p>left: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :leftpx %></p>

  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```